# How to structure AWS DynamoDB Table with Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, relational-database, amazon-cognito

I am trying to do something that would be relatively simple for a relational database but I don't know how to do it for a nonrelational one.

I am trying to make a simple task web app on AWS where people can post their tasks.

I have a table called tasks which uses the userid from the auth token provisioned by AWS Cognito. I am wondering how I can return the user information. I do not want to rely on Cognito by simply calling it every time a user sends a request. So, my thought would be to create another table to store all of the user information. That, however, is not a very nonrelational way of doing things since JOINS are so bad.

So, I was wondering if I should do any of the following
a) Using RDS instead
b) Not use Cognito and set up my own Auth system
c) Just doing the JOIN with a table containing all of the user info
d) Doing the request to Cognito each time

Answer (score 2):

Although I personally like the idea of cognito, at this time it has some major drawbacks...

1. You can not backup / restore a user pool without loosing their password, also you have to implement your own backup/restore.
   A way around is to save the user password in a cognito custom attribute.
2. I expected by using api gateway/lambda authorizer to have all the user data in the lambda context but its not there. Or am indoing something wrong with api gateway template mapping

Good thing api gateway/lambda authorizer, can be cached by up to an hour, wont call the authorizer function again which seems like a top feature.

3. Does not work well with cloudformation, with every attribute update it recreates the user pool without restoring the users, thus loosing the users.

I used it only in one implementation and ended up duplicating the users in DynamoDB as well.

I'm avoiding it ever since. I wish they solve these issues as it looks like a service to be included with every project saving lot of time.

Reading your post I asked myself the same questions and not sure the answer either

Pricing seems fair.

The default 5 requests/second to get user info seems strange as it woukd be consumed by one page load doing multiple ajax api requests .

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am a student trying to learn how to build a scalable system. I know it isn't likely that I will be able to build something with high demand but I still want to learn 'the right way.' Would you recommend trying to create my own JWT auth system? What I am doing now is using Cognito with a plan to hopefully replace it. But, the interface should still remain the same. Also, I have since moved to RDS because I felt I was imposing a relational model on a nonrelational db if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0):

For this in DynamoDB, there is no need for another table. If the access patterns dictate you store the information in another object, then so be it, but more than likely it should be in the same table. Sounds like you need two different item types in the same table.

For the task PK of userid and SK of task::your-task-id. This would allow you to get all of a user's tasks easily or even a specific task very easily if you knew the task ID. You might even have an attribute that is a timestamp and then have a GSI that is the userID as the PK and the timestamp as the SK. then you could use the begins_with operator on the SK and "paginate through all of the user's tasks that are in the month of 2019-04".

For the user information, have the userID be the PK and the SK be user_info and attributes be the user's information.

The one challenge for this is if you were to go to extremes and one single user is doing thousands of ops per second. e.g. "All tweets by very popular celebrity". If you have such a use case there are ways around that as well, e.g. [write sharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html). These are just examples for you to play with. Without knowing all your access patterns, I cannot model everything you might want to do. I highly recommend you go watch [this presentation from reInvent 2018](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEPXoXVf2k).